# Find Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find

I started a easy demo by writing

```
Sub search()
Range("B1:B7").Find("abc").Activate
End Sub
```

I was hoping that excel will auto select a cell contains value "abc" in it, however, I got an error message saying "object variable or with block variable not set". Did I miss anything at all please

Appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the following link. It will show the proper way to identify the object and search. Then just add an Activate for the cell that was found.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

```
    Sub tester()
    With Worksheets(6).Range("B1:B500")
        Set c = .Find("Smith Jon Junior", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address ' not required
            c.Activate
        else
            msgbox ("Not Found")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes, it is really helpful

Comment: always explicitly specify `LookAt` and `LookIn` parameters values otherwise Excel will use their setting at "last" `Find()` using, even if made from Excel UI