# How to I get pass error message in Find Box?

Tags: excel, vba, find, office365

I'm trying to open a customized find box from vba that searches entire sheet. Also when I put a search string it must be selected automatically so that I can put the next string without having to select the first one manually.

I found this code to open find box from vba.

```
Sub FineMe()

    Cells.Find(What:=InputBox("Please enter your search criteria", "Search"), _
    After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False).Activate

End Sub
```

The problem is, if a string is not found I get an error message. Please help me get pass this.

Thank You

Comment: Search and you shall find :) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328395/using-the-find-function-in-vba/31307745) [2](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940542/find-function-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check what is found before you try to use it. And try not put everything all on one line.

```
Sub FineMe()
    Dim Found As Range
    
    Set Found = Cells.Find(What:=InputBox("Please enter your search criteria", "Search"), _
    After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False)
    
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    Else
        Found.Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Activate Next Cell Containing a String

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindMe()
    
    ' Prevent
    '     "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"
    ' occuring when no visible (unhidden) workbook is open.
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No sheet is active.", vbInformation, "FindMe"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Prevent
    '     "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Cells' of object '_Global' failed"
    ' occuring when a chart is active.
    If ActiveSheet.Type <> xlWorksheet Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet is active.", vbInformation, "FindMe"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Input string.
    Dim Criteria As String
    Criteria = InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Please enter your search criteria", _
        Title:="Search", _
        Default:="") ' "Default" could be useful
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the next found cell (after
    ' the active cell) containing the string.
    Dim fCell As Range
    Set fCell = Cells.Find( _
        What:=Criteria, _
        After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
    ' If the string is only contained in hidden cells, by using 'xlValues'
    ' (instead of 'xlFormulas') the string will not be found. Think about
    ' if it is useful finding a string contained in a formula and/or
    ' activating a hidden cell. Best experiment yourself.
    
    ' Test if the reference was created i.e. the string was found.
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the string '" & Criteria & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "Find Me"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    fCell.Activate

End Sub
```